# How to import jQuery in a React component?

Tags: jquery, reactjs

My JS file containing jQuery (apiCalls.js):

```
function getBlogInfo() {
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/myblog.tumblr.com/info?api_key=my-api-key",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(info){
      console.log(info);
      console.log(info.response.blog.likes);
    }
  }
)}  
export { getBlogInfo };
```

My React component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import { getBlogInfo } from './scripts/apiCalls';

class Homepage extends Component {
       componentDidMount(){
        getBlogInfo();

      }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="homepage">

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Homepage;
```

If I replace the `getBlogInfo()` in `componentDidMount()` with the entire script, then the script executes as expected, but using the function call to execute the script gives me an error saying -

```
./src/components/scripts/apiCalls.js
  Line 2:  '$' is not defined  no-undef
```

What I have tried so far:

importing $ from 'jquery' in all my react files.

importing the jquery library in index.html via script tags

Comment: use
import $ from 'jquery'; 
in your apiCalls.js as you are using $ in your apicalls.js no need to import it in your react component

Comment: It worked, thanks! I spent hours searching for a solution, can't believe it was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **jquery** npm in your react project.

```
npm install jquery --save
```

Then use like this.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```